# Why can I not connect vpn with Windows 8 and Cisco VPN?

Tags: vpn, rdp, windows-8

I've installed Cisco VPN Client to connect with remote desktop but it doesn't work. When I try to connect with Remote Desktop I get this error:

```
"Cant connect with remote server...."
```

If I try with Windows XP and Windows 7 I don't have any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The legacy Cisco VPN client has been deemed "unsupported" by cisco, so they push the Anyconnect client as the supported solution. However, I guess some people have had luck modifying a registry key:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\CVirtA
and changing the displayname by removing everything and up to %;
Then restart the client and try connecting again... good luck.

Aroq